# Batch "invalid command-line parameters"

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-2000

For whatever reason, this:

```
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Setup\BeginSecond
/v begin-second /t REG_DWORD /f
/d "%HOMEDRIVE%\Documents and Settings\%USERNAME%\Desktop\bat script\begin-second"
```

- Line feeds were added for readability, the command itself is one continuous line.

Produces the message `"Invalid command-line parameters"` when the program is run. The command before that adds the registry key `"BeginSecond"`, so that's not the issue...

But, for some strange reason, this command worked perfectly fine before I booted up my Windows 2000 virtual machine today.

There is probably some super easy fix for this. Any help, please?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to add a `REG_DWORD` instead of a `REG_SZ` registry value? Also, the error could be caused by having insufficient security rights to write to the specified registry key. Writing to the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` registry key and any of its subkeys usually requires administrative rights.

Comment: Not the solution, but: why using `%HOMEDRIVE%\Documents and Settings\%USERNAME%` rather than `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%`? why not even use `%USERPROFILE%` instead?